# Eclipse Generic File Templates

Tags: sql, eclipse, shell, templates

I've seen this question in various guises around the place, but as yet haven't found a suitable answer. If this is a duplicate, appologies (I'd be surprised if it wasn't a duplicate!)

Basically, I have a project which is using (mostly) shell code and sql. I want to make sure all the files have a similar setup, and that I document things consistently. To this end, I want to have template files / skeleton code within Eclipse.

It seems easy enough with Java, but not other file types. I have checked out ShellEd and it didn't appear to have this feature (correct me if I'm wrong).

It would be great to be able to add this as a new file type, such that I can say File -> New -> sh/sql and have the correct basic template with the right header etc.

Also, if possible I would like to be able to, one click, add a function prototype with the correct documentation to my files...

I thought this would be easy enough, but a few days of Googling and messing about, it seems I need to write a plugin of my own... but I can't beleive that it's not possible, more likely my Google skills aren't up to scratch...

any help?

cheers
Rob

P.S I'm normally a Vi (not Vim) user, but have had Eclipse forced upon me!

Comment: Incidentally, I have had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865830/generic-code-snippets-templates-in-eclipse?rq=1, but could not seem to get WTP to work - if anyone has a good resource for this, that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL the Data Tools Platform Extender SDK (DTP) Eclipse project contains a SQL editor with templates (under Database Development in Install New Software).

Comment: cheers greg... seems this is the best I can hope for! Seems strange huh? I'll accept your answer so this doesn't stay open - you've answered half the question, and we hope for a solution somewhere. Beginning to think it might be quicker to embed vim in a custom editor